# Flutter - GestureDetector is not detecting in animation

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using an animation that fills in blue across the screen by tapping the `FloatingActionButton`. And giving another tap on the `FloatingActionButton` the blue exits the screen. As the gif below:

[image]

I put a `GestureDetector` in the animation so that after the screen is filled with blue, when tapping the blue, it exits the screen. Like I tapped the `FloatingActionButton` again.

However, `GestureDetector` is not detecting any tap in any part of the blue on the screen, even though I put it in `onTap: (){print("test")}` `GestureDetector` does not detect.

Could someone help me so that by tapping on blue it runs the `_up()` function again?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new HomePage()));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() => new HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _animation;
  bool upDown = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 180),
    );

    _animation = new CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: new Interval(0.0, 1.0, curve: Curves.linear),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ui.Size logicalSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double _width = logicalSize.width;
    final double _height = logicalSize.height;

    void _up(){
      setState((){
        if(upDown) {
          upDown = false;
          _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
        } else {
          upDown = true;
          _controller.reverse(from: 1.0);
        }
      });
    }

    return new Scaffold(
        body: new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Positioned(
                  bottom: 0.0,
                  child: new GestureDetector(
                    onTap: _up,
                    child: new AnimatedBuilder(
                      animation: _animation,
                      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                      return new Container(
                        height: _height,
                        child: new CustomPaint(
                          painter: new Sky(_width, _height * _animation.value),
                          child: new Container(
                            height: _isRotated ? 0.0 : _height * _animation.value,
                            width: _isRotated ? 0.0 : _width,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ),
              new Positioned(
                bottom: 16.0,
                right: 16.0,
                child: new FloatingActionButton(
                  backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFE57373),
                  child: new Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: (){
                    _up();
                  },
                )
              )
            ]
        )
    );
  }
}

class Sky extends CustomPainter {
  final double _width;
  double _rectHeight;

  Sky(this._width, this._rectHeight);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawRect(
      new Rect.fromLTRB(
          0.0, size.height - _rectHeight, this._width, size.height
      ),
      new Paint()..color = new Color.fromRGBO(0, 153, 255, 0.9)
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(Sky oldDelegate) {
    return _width != oldDelegate._width || _rectHeight != oldDelegate._rectHeight;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GestureDetector` will only work on a widget. `CustomPaint` is not a widget, so it was necessary to put in the `child` property of `CustomPaint` a widget such as a `Container`.

Here's how `CustomPaint`:

```
...
child: new CustomPaint(
  painter: new Sky(_width, _height * _animation.value),
  child: new Container(
    height: _isRotated ? 0.0 : _height * _animation.value,
    width: _isRotated ? 0.0 : _width,
  ),
),
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There's already something that does the work for you : Scaffold.

Use `Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet`
And it does everything you need in one line of code.

You can also use `showModalBottomSheet` (which seems to have a max height limit).

```
void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Test(),
  ));
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("data"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new MyButton(),
    );
  }
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FloatingActionButton(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      onPressed: () => onPressed(context),
      child: new Icon(Icons.plus_one),
    );
  }

  void onPressed(BuildContext context) {
    Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet((context) {
      return new Container(
        color: Colors.cyan,
      );
    });
  }
}
```